# Angular data does not show on loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs, parse-platform

The ng-binding which isn't show on loading uses data from an array in scope. 
The array gets the data from another arrays( let's call them A). 
The ng-binding which was already shown on loading use the data from the arrays A.

[image: Data doesn't show]
[image: Data show]
Here are several ways to show the data WHICH ARE REALLY WEIRD:
- Focus then not focus any of the inputs
- Change the value of any of the inputs

You can try the bug [here](http://185.26.50.123/playgrounds/playground3/).

Here I provide some pieces of my code:

```
      <div class="container-fluid " id="mainApp"> 

                <div class="container" ng-repeat='content in fetchedData'>

                  <h4>{{content[1]}}</h4>

                  <div class="row" ng-repeat='data in content[2]'>
                  <p class="pull-left">{{data[0]}}<p>
                  <input data-toggle='tooltip' title ='{{data[1]}} hours per page'  ng-model='data[2]' type='number' min=0 class='form-control numberInput pull-right'>
                  </div>

                </div>

                   <div class="container">

                    <h4>{{languageData[0]}}</h4>

                    <div class="row" >
                    <p class="pull-left">{{languageData[1][0][0]}}<p>
                    <input data-toggle='tooltip' title ='{{languageData[1][0][1]}} hours per page'  ng-model='languageData[1][0][2]' type='number' min=0 class='form-control numberInput pull-right'>
                    </div>

                  </div>
      </div>
```

The js code file for fetching the for the `languageData`:

```
$scope.getLangData = function (){
            var langData = [];
            var langPanel = Parse.Object.extend("Panel");

            var langpanelObject = new Parse.Query(langPanel);

            langpanelObject.equalTo('editable',false);
            langpanelObject.find( {
                success:function(results) 
                {
                    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                             langData.push(results[i].get("title"),[],results[i].id);
                    };

                    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.fetchedRows.length; i++) {
                        if ($scope.fetchedRows[i][3]== langData[2]) {
                            langData[1].push($scope.fetchedRows[i]);
                        }
                    };
                },
                error:function(error) 
                {
                    alert("Error: "+ error.code + " " +error.message);
                }
            });
            $scope.languageData = langData;
            $scope.$apply();
}
```

I guess it is the js code that causes this bug because I have a button, that fire getLangData() function on click (which is `Reset` button in the site), and the data disappears again. However, I have no idea how and why it affects the visibility of the ng-binding.

Comment: Why `$scope.$apply();` its throwing error in console. You no need use `$scope.$apply();'` because scope gets digested automatically in controller

Comment: I used it because the ng binding to the html is loaded before the data is fetched. So after the data is available to be shown, I think I should use $apply so it will update the binding.
What error do you have? I have no error from the console. I tried to remove apply in the code but the problem is still there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$scope.$apply()` is being run before your asynchronous call is resolved.

Since Parse library is out of the angular thread, you have to run an `$apply` to the scope, but the right way would be this:

```js
langpanelObject.find( {
    success: function(results) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            langData.push(results[i].get("title"),[],results[i].id);
        };

        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.fetchedRows.length; i++) {
            if ($scope.fetchedRows[i][3]== langData[2]) {
                langData[1].push($scope.fetchedRows[i]);
            }
        };

        $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.languageData = langData;
        });
    },
    error: function(error) {
        alert("Error: "+ error.code + " " +error.message);
    }
});
```

It's a good practice to use `$apply` passing a function as an argument, instead of just `$scope.$apply()`.

Comment: thanks for your answer.
Is it `$scope.$apply(...)` or only `$scope.apply()`?

Comment: It's `$scope.$apply(...)`, sorry, it was a typo, I'm going to fix the answer.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is because Javascript executes scope.$apply() before my languageData is updated.
The solution is to delay the $apply() function by setTimeOut().

```
setTimeout(function(){ $scope.$apply();}, 500);
```

Comment: Is not a good practice to just delay some code without reason. Please, see my solution.